# RegEx in JavaScript .split()

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I need to split up a string like this

```
<p>foo</p><p>bar</p>
```

to an array with "foo" and "bar"

I thought RegEx could help me, but it seems I didn't understand RegEx. This is my try.

```
var inputText = "<p>foo</p><p>bar</p>";
splittedSelection = inputText.split("/<p>|<\/p>/g");
```

But all I can achieve is an array with one entry and it's the same as the inputText.

[I made a little fiddle for you.](https://jsfiddle.net/5rxa6csn/2/)

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You're not using a regex here, you're using a string. `splittedSelection = inputText.split(/<p>|<\/p>/g);`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454

Comment: Thanks for that, @epascarello. Everybody go click that link

Comment: [Do not parse HTML with Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/6320039)

Comment: Please take a look at @baao's answer :)

Comment: I should have been more specific about my aim. I need exactly the parts between the open and closed <p> tags. I need to modify the stuff between with all the other HTML-Tags that may be or may be not be inside those tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `/<p>|<\/p>/g` instead of inside quotations. However, this will produce `["", "foo", "", "bar", ""]`, which is undesirable, so you can `.filter()` out empty results, like this:

```js
var inputText = "<p>foo</p><p>bar</p>";

splittedSelection = inputText.split(/<p>|<\/p>/g).filter(function(value) {
  // Filter out empty results
  return value !== "";
});

document.getElementById("bar").innerHTML += "0: " + splittedSelection[0] + "\n" + "1: " + splittedSelection[1] + "\n";
```

```html
<div id="bar">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can start from something like this:

1. `.+` will handle different tags and attributes
2. `.+?` creates a `lazy quantifier`

```js
const text = "<p>foo</p><p>bar</p>";

const re = /<.+?>(.+?)<\/.+?>/g;

console.log(text.split(re).filter(t => t));
```

Comment: "Lazy quantifier" = "By adding the ? after the +, we tell it to repeat as few times as possible, so the first match it comes across, is where we want to stop the matching." – lazy vs. greedy https://stackoverflow.com/a/2301298/1066234

Answer (score 0):

ES6 based answer:

```
const regex = /<[^>]*>/gi;
let string = '<p>foo</p><p>bar</p>';
let result = string.split(regex).filter(e => e);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Forget about the answers that try to fix your regex. Don't do it with regex**.

Instead, get the elements and map their textContent to an array:

```js
let res = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('p')).map(e => e.textContent);
console.log(res);
```

```html
<p>foo</p><p>bar</p>
```

If you only have this string and it is not a part of the document, create an element and parse it then (you don't even need to append the element to the DOM):

```js
let s = "<p>foo</p><p>bar</p>";
let el = document.createElement('div');
el.innerHTML = s;

let res = Array.from(el.getElementsByTagName('p')).map(e => e.textContent);
console.log(res);
```

If you're doing this in node, you can use [cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio):

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio')
let html = "<p>foo</p><p>bar</p>";
const $ = cheerio.load(html);
let res = [];
$('p').each((i,e) => res.push($(e).text()));
console.log(res);
```

If you are doing this in any other environment, changes are extremely high that there's a DOM/XML/HTML parser available, too.

Comment: This is like offering apples to who's asking for milk, isn't it? What's about this task should be done in nodejs?

Comment: No it isn't @Hitmands. It's explaining someone who is doing it wrong how to do it right. If you ask me how to jump from a bridge I'd also say better don't do it instead of explaining your original question. I've added a version for node...

Comment: All of us are aware that `Regex shouldn't be used as parsers`, but, he his asking for that... You can add a comment with a suggestion to better handle the problem but answers should be answers...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is on the client you can use jQuery instead of regex.

```js
var inputText = "<p>foo</p><p>bar</p>";
var splittedSelection = $('<div>'+inputText+'</div>').find("p").map(function() { 
  return $(this).text() 
});
$.each(splittedSelection, function(i,item) {
  $("#bar").append(i+": " +item + "<br/>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="bar"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution with regex:

```js
let regex = /(?![<p>])(.*?)(?=[<\/p>])/g
  , inputText = "<p>foo</p><p>bar</p>";

let array = inputText.match(regex).filter(i => i);
  
console.log(array);
```